# Different variable every time in forloop

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Im trying to get this script more automated by getting data from a database rather then type each loop out 1 by 1.

This is what ive got:

I want the variable "$test" to be different everytime, So for example ill have the results as follows:

```
$test1 = "entry1;entry2;entry3;";
$test2 = "entry1;entry2;entry3;";
```

This is the script ive got, It works fine for the one variable test but i need lots of results in different variables.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM course";
$result = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$course_menuname = $row['course_menuname']; #E.G breakfast_cereal, breakfast_toast, lunch_main
$course_item = $row['course_jsname']; #E.G cereal, toast, jacketpotato
 if(!empty($_POST[''.$course_menuname.''])) {
   foreach($_POST[''.$course_menuname.''] as $course_item) {
    $course_item = trim($course_item);
    if(!empty($course_item)) {
      $test .= "$course_item;";
    }
   }
 }
}

echo $test;
```

This is what i had before multiple times but i want it to be more automated.

```
 if(!empty($_POST['lunchmain_selection'])) {
   foreach($_POST['lunchmain_selection'] as $lunchmain) {
    $lunchmain = trim($lunchmain);
    if(!empty($lunchmain)) {
      $lunchmainchoices .= "$lunchmain;";
    }
   }
  }
 if(!empty($_POST['jacketpotato_selection'])) {
   foreach($_POST['jacketpotato_selection'] as $lunchjacketpotato) {
    $lunchjacketpotato = trim($lunchjacketpotato);
    if(!empty($lunchjacketpotato)) {
      $lunchjacketpotatochoices .= "$lunchjacketpotato;";
    }
```

}
  }

Comment: You've identified your redundant code. Try putting that into a function which takes a string like `lunchmain_selection` or `jacketpotato_selection` as an argument. It should be simpler to work out how to use that function in a loop.

Comment: It's very unclear what you're trying to accomplish. Your current code would print out the same variable from the database based on the number of menu items you have. Your output isn't clear. Are the entry1;entry2 etc values from the menu or from the database?

Comment: Yeah ive confused myself, I really can't figure it out. the entry1;entry2; are coming from this form:     http://i.imgur.com/nEpg92q.png So i want it to a varible holding each of the categorys of the form, for example: $breakfast_cereal = "entry1;entry2;"; and then $breakfast_toast = "entry3;entry4;"; etc etc, Does that help ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use functions: here's an example

```
function thisLoopDoesSomething($loop_array) {
    // Don't bother doing anything if it's an empty array
    if (!empty($loop_array)) {
        return;
    }

    // Your loop code here, using the passed in variable
}

thisLoopDoesSomething($_POST['lunchmain_selection']);
thisLoopDoesSomething($_POST['jacketpotato_selection']);
...
```